# Swing Timer is not starting in a Java GUI *UPDATED

Tags: java

I am trying to make a GUI Application that makes a game of Bingo. I'm using a swing Timer in order to create a new call every 4 seconds (ex. O63) and updates the call board. However, it seems like the timer never starts. It works if I put the action listener to a button but not for the timer. I cant figure it out so any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory; 
import javax.swing.border.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.Random;

public class Bin1 {

private static JPanel panel = new JPanel();
private static JPanel panelcb = new JPanel();
private static JPanel panelcb1 = new JPanel();
private static JPanel panelcs = new JPanel();
private static JPanel panelcpu = new JPanel();
private static JPanel panelp = new JPanel();
private static Border border = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black, 1);
private static JLabel[] brow;
private static JLabel[] irow;
private static JLabel[] nrow;
private static JLabel[] grow;
private static JLabel[] orow;
private static Timer timer;
private static JLabel call;


private static JLabel[] boardbin(String letter, int col){
    JLabel[] row = new JLabel[16];
    JLabel let = new JLabel(" " + letter + " ");
    row[0] = let;
    row[0].setBorder(border);
    row[0].setForeground(Color.MAGENTA);
    panelcb.add(row[0]);
    for(int i = 1; i < 16; i++){
        JLabel x = new JLabel( "  " + ("" + (i + (15 * col))) + " " );
        row[i] = x;
        row[i].setBorder(border);
        row[i].setForeground(Color.blue);
        panelcb.add(row[i]);
        }
    return row;
}

/*private static void pcallb(int x){
    if(x == 0){
        for(int b = 0; b < 15; b++){
            panelcb.add(brow[b]);
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < 15; i++){
            panelcb.add(irow[i]);
        }
        for(int n = 0; n < 15; n++){
            panelcb.add(nrow[n]);
        }
        for(int g = 0; g < 15; g++){
            panelcb.add(grow[g]);
        }
        for(int o = 0; o < 15; o++){
            panelcb.add(orow[o]);
        }
    }else{
        for(int b = 0; b < 15; b++){
            panelcb1.add(brow[b]);
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < 15; i++){
            panelcb1.add(irow[i]);
        }
        for(int n = 0; n < 15; n++){
            panelcb1.add(nrow[n]);
        }
        for(int g = 0; g < 15; g++){
            panelcb1.add(grow[g]);
        }
        for(int o = 0; o < 15; o++){
            panelcb1.add(orow[o]);
        }
    }
}*/

private static void callb(int x){
    if(x == 0){
        brow = new JLabel[15];
        brow = boardbin("B", 0);
        irow = new JLabel[15];
        irow = boardbin("I", 1);
        nrow = new JLabel[15];
        nrow = boardbin("N", 2);
        grow = new JLabel[15];
        grow = boardbin("G", 3);
        orow = new JLabel[15];
        orow = boardbin("O", 4);
        //pcallb(0);
    }else{
        //pcallb(1);
    }
}

private static void biname(String letter, int jbl){
    if(jbl == 0){
        JLabel b = new JLabel("    " + letter);
        b.setBorder(border);
        b.setForeground(Color.magenta);
        panelcpu.add(b);
    }else{
        JLabel b = new JLabel("    " + letter);
        b.setBorder(border);
        b.setForeground(Color.magenta);
        panelp.add(b);
    }
}

private static void cardcpu(){
    Random rand = new Random();
    biname("B", 0);
    biname("I", 0);
    biname("N", 0);
    biname("G", 0);
    biname("O", 0);
    JLabel a = new JLabel(" ");
    panelcpu.add(a);
    biname("B", 0);
    biname("I", 0);
    biname("N", 0);
    biname("G", 0);
    biname("O", 0);
    for(int h = 0; h < 10; h++){
        if(h % 2 == 0){
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
                    if(h == 4 && i == 2 || h == 5 && i == 2){
                        JLabel c = new JLabel("*");
                        c.setBorder(border);
                        c.setForeground(Color.blue);
                        panelcpu.add(c);
                    }else{
                        String num = Integer.toString(rand.nextInt(15) + 1 + i * 15);
                        JLabel c = new JLabel(num);
                        c.setBorder(border);
                        c.setForeground(Color.blue);
                        panelcpu.add(c);    
                    }
            }
            JLabel b = new JLabel(" ");
            panelcpu.add(b);
        }else{
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
                if(h == 4 && i == 2 || h == 5 && i == 2){
                    JLabel c = new JLabel("*");
                    c.setBorder(border);
                    c.setForeground(Color.blue);
                    panelcpu.add(c);
                }else{
                    String num = Integer.toString(rand.nextInt(15) + 1 + i * 15);
                    JLabel c = new JLabel(num);
                    c.setBorder(border);
                    c.setForeground(Color.blue);
                    panelcpu.add(c);    
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

private static void cardp(){
    Random rand = new Random();
    biname("B", 1);
    biname("I", 1);
    biname("N", 1);
    biname("G", 1);
    biname("O", 1);
    JLabel a = new JLabel(" ");
    panelp.add(a);
    biname("B", 1);
    biname("I", 1);
    biname("N", 1);
    biname("G", 1);
    biname("O", 1);
    for(int h = 0; h < 10; h++){
        if(h % 2 == 0){
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
                    if(h == 4 && i == 2 || h == 5 && i == 2){
                        JButton c = new JButton("*");
                        c.setBorder(border);
                        c.setForeground(Color.blue);
                        panelp.add(c);
                    }else{
                        String num = Integer.toString(rand.nextInt(15) + 1 + i * 15);
                        JButton c = new JButton(num);
                    //  c.addActionListener(new ButtonAction());
                        c.setBorder(border);
                        c.setForeground(Color.blue);
                        panelp.add(c);  
                    }
            }
            JLabel b = new JLabel(" ");
            panelp.add(b);
        }else{
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
                if(h == 4 && i == 2 || h == 5 && i == 2){
                    JButton c = new JButton("*");
                    c.setBorder(border);
                    c.setForeground(Color.blue);
                    panelp.add(c);
                }else{
                    String num = Integer.toString(rand.nextInt(15) + 1 + i * 15);
                    JButton c = new JButton(num);
                    //c.addActionListener(new ButtonAction());
                    c.setBorder(border);
                    c.setForeground(Color.blue);
                    panelp.add(c);  
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

public static void main (String[] args) {
    timer = new Timer(4000, new ButtonAction());
    timer.start();
    Border border2 = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black, 2);
    JFrame frame = new JFrame ("Bingo");
    frame.setVisible(true);
    //frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH); 
    frame.setResizable(true);
    frame.setSize(750, 750);
    frame.setContentPane(panel);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    panel.setSize(new Dimension(400, 600));
    panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(5, 17));
    panel.add(panelcb);
    panel.add(panelcs);

    TitledBorder title;
    title = BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(border2, "CALL BOARD");
    title.setTitleColor(Color.GREEN);
    title.setTitleFont(new Font("Dialog", Font.BOLD, 15));
    panelcb.setBorder(title);
    panelcb.setSize(new Dimension(400, 600));
    panelcb.setLayout(new GridLayout(5, 17));
    callb(0);  

    panelcb1.setBorder(title);
    panelcb1.setSize(new Dimension(400, 600));
    panelcb1.setLayout(new GridLayout(5, 17));
    callb(1); 

    panelcs.setSize(new Dimension(400, 600));
    panelcs.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 2));
    panelcs.add(panelcpu);
    panelcs.add(panelp);

    TitledBorder titlecpu;
    titlecpu = BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(border2, "CPU BOARD");
    titlecpu.setTitleColor(Color.blue);
    titlecpu.setTitleFont(new Font("Dialog", Font.BOLD, 15));
    panelcpu.setBorder(titlecpu);
    panelcpu.setSize(new Dimension(600, 600));
    panelcpu.setLayout(new GridLayout(6, 11));
    cardcpu();

    TitledBorder titlep;
    titlep = BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(border2, "PLAYER BOARD");
    titlep.setTitleColor(Color.red);
    titlep.setTitleFont(new Font("Dialog", Font.BOLD, 15));
    panelp.setBorder(titlep);
    panelp.setSize(new Dimension(600, 600));
    panelp.setLayout(new /*FlowLayout()*/ GridLayout(6, 14));
    cardp();

    JLabel bottom = new JLabel("Get Ready To Play Bingo!");
    bottom.setForeground(Color.magenta);
    bottom.setFont(new Font("Dialog", Font.BOLD, 20));
    panel.add(bottom);

}

public static class ButtonAction implements ActionListener {

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        Random rand = new Random();
        String n = Integer.toString(rand.nextInt(75));
        JLabel ca = new JLabel(n);
        call = ca;
        JLabel star = new JLabel("*");
        int x = Integer.parseInt(n);
        //panel.add(call);
        if(x >= 1 && x <= 15){
            for(int b = 0; b < 15; b++){
                if(call == brow[b]){
                    brow[b] = star;
                    JLabel upcallb = new JLabel("B" + n);
                    call = upcallb;
                    panel.add(call);
                }
            }
        }else if(x >= 16 && x <= 30){
            for(int i = 0; i < 15; i++){
                if(call == irow[i]){
                    irow[i] = star;
                    JLabel upcalli = new JLabel("I" + n);
                    call = upcalli;
                    panel.add(call);
                }
            }
        }else if(x >= 31 && x <= 45){
            for(int m = 0; m < 15; m++){
                if(call == nrow[m]){
                    nrow[m] = star;
                    JLabel upcalln = new JLabel("N" + n);
                    call = upcalln;
                    panel.add(call);
                }
            }
        }else if(x >= 46 && x <= 60){
            for(int g = 0; g < 15; g++){ 
                if(call == grow[g]){
                    grow[g] = star;
                    JLabel upcallg = new JLabel("G" + n);
                    call = upcallg;
                    panel.add(call);
                }
            }
        }else{
            for(int o = 0; o < 15; o++){
                if(call == orow[o]){
                    orow[o] = star;
                    JLabel upcallo = new JLabel("O" + n);
                    call = upcallo;
                    panel.add(call);
                }
            }
        }
        timer.restart();
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I’m not sure if this is the cause of your problems, but a Timer restarting itself seems suspect.  Consider calling [timer.setRepeats(true)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/Timer.html#setRepeats%28boolean%29) right after creating the Timer (not from within the ActionListener).

Comment: @VGR thanks for the suggestion, but I already figured out why the timer would not start. However, another problem is persisting. It seems to skip over the if statement in the eventlistener. It fires off but ignores only the if statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears your Timer is in fact running, but the following expressions always evaluate to false:

- `if (call == brow[b])`
- `if (call == irow[i])`
- `if (call == nrow[m])`
- `if (call == grow[g])`
- `if (call == orow[o])`

This is because `call` is null.  At no time is `call` set to an element of any of those arrays.

Note that `JLabel call = new JLabel();` creates a *new local variable* named `call` which is not related to your `private static JLabel call;` declaration.  But even if it were, setting `call` to a new JLabel would not cause the above if-tests to succeed.

Comment: I've updated the code to make sure 'call' was not null but it still skips over the if statement. Thanks

Comment: You are now setting `call` to a brand new JLabel.  A brand new JLabel will never be present in any of those arrays, unless you explicitly assign an array element to that JLabel.

Comment: To be honest, I am kind of confused because I'm trying to compare the 'call' value to the values in the array to see if there is a match, so I don't see why 'call' itself would need to be in the array. Thanks again for your continued help.

Comment: The `==` operator in Java, when applied to objects rather than numbers, checks for *reference equality.*  This means the two values on either side of `==` must be exactly the same object.  Not similar objects. Not even identical objects.  They must be the same object, for the test to evaluate to true.  You might have better results by testing the JLabels’ text properties:  `if (call.getText().trim().equals(brow[b].getText().trim()))`  (You cannot compare Strings with `==`.)

Comment: Thank you so much. You are actually a lifesaver. I did not know you could not compare them using ==. It's working now.